# Convert 7FFFFFFF to the decimal equivalent?

Tags: hex, nan

I saw somewhere that this is a special case and that +NaN goes from 0x7F800001 to 0x7FFFFFFF. Is the answer +NaN?

Answer (score 2):

If you interpret `7FFFFFFF` as an IEEE754 32-bit float then yes, `7FFFFFFF` is NaN.  You can understand these things from looking at the Wikipedia page for [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format). I wrote this little C program to illustrate the point:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  unsigned u0 = 0x7FFFFFFF;
  unsigned u1 = 0x7F800001;
  unsigned u2 = 0x7F800000;
  unsigned u3 = 0x7F7FFFFF;

  // *(float*)&u0 causes the data stored in u0 to be interpreted as a float
  printf("%e\n", *(float*)&u0);  // This gives nan
  printf("%e\n", *(float*)&u1);  // This also gives nan
  printf("%e\n", *(float*)&u2);  // This gives inf
  printf("%e\n", *(float*)&u3);  // This gives 3.402823e+38, the largest possible IEEE754 32-bit float

  // The above code only works because sizeof(unsigned)==sizeof(float)
  printf("%u\t%u\n", sizeof(unsigned), sizeof(float));

  // Remember that nan is only for floats, u0 is a perfectly valid unsigned.
  printf("%u\n", u0);            // This gives 2147483647

}
```

Again, it has to be mentioned that NaN only exists as a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

+NaN is a special value for floating point numbers (And it has no decimal equivalent. It's "Not a Number").
If you just want the decimal representation of the integer, which has 7FFFFFFF as hexadecimal representation, there's no floating point involved, and no +NaN

Comment: While technically an accurate summary of the IEEE754 spec, this answer is going to be confusing to anyone who needs to ask the question in the first place. Douglas's answer is more detailed, but be certain to read the code comments.